# What is the opposite of 'wall of text'?

Tags: antonyms

What is the antonym of *[wall of text](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wall_of_text)*? That is, a text where every paragraph is a single sentence.

If the antonym doesn't exist, how can the opposite of *wall of text* be described grammar-technically? There must be a term or a description for this common type of error in writing.

#### Exhibit A <sup>[1]</sup>

> object is valid for all .NET versions. 
>
> It is the base type that all other types inherit from, so any type can be cast to object. 
>
> You can't dynamically add and change anything on a variable declared as object. 
>
> The declaration is a statically typed and checked by the compiler. 
>
> dynamic is new for .NET 4.0. 
>
> It allows you do dynamically add and change properties and methods without the compiler checking them (so if what you wrote is wrong you will only find out at runtime).

---

<sub>1. Reference: [Raw text](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/b1252181-d1b1-425e-b8e9-622fed5f0fa9/view-source). [Rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25125594/1).</sub>

Comment: I considered [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour), but then I saw [a meta post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3878/reconsidering-the-single-word-request).

Comment: 'brief'?*******

Comment: Excessively-spaced?

Comment: Old-fashioned, but apt:  "telegraph style". They were always terse, because they were charged by the word.

Answer (score 3):

According to the definition you cite (and my understanding), a wall of text is a solid blob of text without paragraph breaks.  It is therefore hard to mentally outline a "wall of text".  Your example seems to be of the "opposite of a wall of text" that you seek a word for.

Some words that might help:

- "broken up"
- "staccato"
- "disjointed"
- "not fleshed out"
- "outline"

Answer (score 3):

Maybe *point form* or *note form*. You could describe it as *sparse*.

Answer (score 2):

After a little research online, I believe there is no set term for what you're describing. I think the next best thing is to use a descriptive:

> a scrawny line of text
>
> a measly blurb in the middle of the page

etc.

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

Yes, I think *[TL;DR](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TLDR)* can be used as an antonym of *wall of text*.

They were both born in the Information Age; aren't they a perfect pair? :-)

---

Usually, *TL;DR* is used in a similar way we use *Synopsis* or *Executive Summary* (or just *Summary*).

Your text looks like a *summary*; it contains several *summarized points* (which makes it look similar to a bullet list, just without the bullet points). If I have to describe that block of your example text, I think I'd call it ***summarized points, in short***, and probably head it with either ***TL;DR*** or ***Summary***, depending on the occasion.

Answer (score 1):

The defining characteristic of a wall of text is its rambling verbosity, not necessarily that it lacks paragraph breaks.  A wall of text with paragraph breaks would still be a wall of text.

A piece of writing that is the opposite of a wall of text might be described as ***succinct***.

Comment: Or even "well-structured"

Answer (score 1):

I would describe Exhibit A as bulletpoints. There isn't actually a bullet point in from of each line, but it seems like there might as well be.

Comment: While this is a reasonable description, the question asks for its antonym.

Answer (score 0):

A document composed entirely of single lines cannot really be said to have "paragraphs".

A "paragraph", by nature, is different from a *sentence*. It *can* be of a single sentence, and [dictionary definitions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/paragraph) note this - but grammar texts state that as a "rule of thumb" (ie, not a hard and fast rule, but generally accepted) a paragraph should have between [3-8 sentences](https://wordcounter.net/blog/2015/11/30/10988_how-many-sentences-in-a-paragraph.html). There is also the "[classic 5-sentence paragraph](http://grubbycup.com/blog/how-to-write-five-sentence-paragraphs-and-five-paragraph-essays/)".

The linked definition of "wall of text" sounds like a term has been coined for a document *without paragraphs*.

The exact opposite that *you* have described - a text where single lines are separated - sounds more like a *bullet-pointed list*, albeit without the bullet points.